# Batch Script to check if existing files inside subdirectories older than a day

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to check if there is any file inside the subdirectories of the current directory, which was last modified a day ago or before.

This would be pretty easy by using the following line if it worked.

```
FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") DO forfiles /p "%%G" /D -1 /C "SET /a exists = 1"
```

However there is a bug with forfiles when executing commands with it and you should call another cmd from it. (See http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)

At the end it needs to be called:

```
FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") DO forfiles /p "%%G" /D -1 /C "cmd /c SET /a exists = 1"
```

The problem with this, is that "exists" would be a local variable in the other cmd session and not the current one, so I won't have it available in my script.

Raymond Chen suggests to use another FOR to actually perform the operation in: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120803-00/?p=6953

This made me write the following line:

```
for /f %%i in ('FOR /D /r %%G in ("*"^) DO forfiles /p %%G /D -1 /C "cmd /c echo 1"') do set exists=%%i
```

However in this scenario, this doesn't work as I have another FOR in between and what gets written to 'exists' is the subdirectory instead of the '1'.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
As mentioned by [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl), switching the placement of both FOR commands made it work, however I'm now with the limitation that it just checks the date and does not care about the time. So a file with modified date of Sep. 15, 2016 23:59 would show up if the script is ran at Sep. 16, 2016 00:00

Comment: `forfiles` cannot execute internal `cmd` commands , unless you state `cmd /C`; this is not a bug; `forfiles` is an external command (not embedded in `cmd`), so it cannot look into `cmd`; the bug you are referring to is for using *external commands* only. Anyway, are you aware that `forfiles` regards the date only, but it does not care about the time? so if a file is last modified yesterday at *23:59*, it will be returned by `forfiles /D -1` today at *00:00*. Nevertheless, to solve your issue, I think you need to place the `for /F` loop around `forfiles`, but *inside* of the `for /D /R` loop...

Comment: Thanks, that did work, however I was not aware that `forfiles` does not care about the time. I probably need another solution then anyways. I'll use this one for now until I get something better working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have to use **FORFILES**?

Does the **/MINAGE** switch of **ROBOCOPY** help?

This should set the %_exists% variable if there are any files older than 1 day:

```
@ECHO OFF

(SET _fold=%USERPROFILE%\MYDIRECTORY)

SET "_exists="
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN (
    'ROBOCOPY /L /S /MINAGE:1 /NS /NC /NP /NDL /NJH /NJS "%_fold%" NULL *.*'
    ) DO SET/A _exists+=1
IF NOT DEFINED _exists EXIT/B

REM Commands here if a file exists
ECHO( Your command is running

TIMEOUT -1 >NUl
EXIT/B
```

*Obviously I've put a command on line 12 just for the hell of it, you would likely change that.*

Comment: I don't have to use `FORFILES` it was just the option I found. Do you know if your option of using `ROBOCOPY` also has the limitation mentioned by @aschipfl that it only checks the date but does not care about the time?

Comment: I also need it to only check subdirectories and not the current directory, this solution doesn't do that as far as I can tell but should be easily changed.

Comment: The **/S** option does exactly that!

Comment: `robocopy`'s `/MINAGE` and `/MAXAGE` switches, like `forfiles /D`, check the *last modification date*, but *not* the creation date; in contrast to `forfiles` however, `robocopy` *does* regard the time, so if you specify `/MINAGE:2`, the last modification is truly `2` days ago at least...

Comment: @Compo, "`2`days" was just an example; I rolled back your change in order the answer to suit to the question...

Comment: @Compo I saw the /S option. But as I have tested that means "including subdirectories" and not "only in subdirectories". What I mean is that it also includes files in the original directory.

Comment: For that you can use the **/XD** option and have your root folder entered in there

Comment: @Compo Unfortunately that didn't work, when using /XD with the root folder, it just excludes everything. I guess I'll use a `FOR` like my original answer but now using `ROBOCOPY` instead of `FORFILES`

Comment: I ended up using `FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") DO FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN ('ROBOCOPY /L /S /MINAGE:1 /NS /NC /NP /NDL /NJH /NJS "%%G" NULL *.*') DO SET/A _exists+=1`